# PlacePicker doesn't pick up material theme

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, android-theme

I am using a [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/) library from Google Play Services which starts up a new activity. The new activity/picker has a toolbar (actionbar) which is not styled by default.

PlacePicker documentation states that

> If you set custom colors in your application using the material theme,
> the place picker inherits the colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark
> attributes from the theme.

I have a theme in my style.xml file:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#5665bb</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#5665bb</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#41456b</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#41456b</item>
</style>
```

and I have set the theme to be used in my Android Manifesto file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

The placepicker is created by the following code:

```
try {
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(Main.this);
    // Start the intent by requesting a result,
    // identified by a request code.
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    Log.e("", "Error with Google Play lib.");
}
```

However, the toolbar doesn't get styled. As before it has a white background and black text.
It's interesting to note that my own toolbar (actionbar) does get styled.

How do I force the placepicker activity to adopt my theme?

Comment: What is the styling used by the launching activity?

Comment: @ianhanniballake a theme is applied to whole application so I would accept all underlying activities should be the same theme.

Comment: So, just to confirm, you have no `android:theme` on the activity that is launching the `PlacePicker`? Can you also include the code you use to create the `PlacePicker`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake that's correct. No theme on the activity but there is theme on the application. I have also added the code used to launch PlacePicker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an [acknowledged issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7968&q=PlacePicker&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal) by the development team.

> There is currently a known issue with setting custom theme colors on
>   the PlacePicker. For now you can work around this by defining two
>   colors with the names "primary" and "primary_dark" - these will be
>   applied to the PlacePicker.
>
> Unfortunately setting the primary/primaryDark property on a theme will
>   not affect the PlacePicker styling at the moment.

EDIT:
Seems to be fixed now.

> This should be fixed in Google Play Services 10.0. Place Picker and
>   Autocomplete Widget will use the colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark
>   colors from your app.

Comment: Did you find the way to change title text color?

Comment: @Max No :( Hopefully they fix that soon.

Comment: Do you know how to get search option there like Hangouts?
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s526/sh/34204375-b79d-4cce-81cb-e569294d42b8/32d08a49b980b45b153fb478d0e2bf3e

Comment: What about the title of the toolbar? What color should i define for it to change? Its black by default

Comment: @Joseph I haven't figured that out myself yet.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify a theme just for the place picker activity? Or at least me let it change the toolbar color from white to something else.

Answer (score 2):

As is mentioned in the documentation that you provided in your question:

> If you set custom colors in your application using the material theme,
>   the place picker inherits the colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark
>   attributes from the theme.

However, you have not specified the *actual* Material theme (`Theme.Material.Light`) in your `style.xml` file; rather, you have utilized `Theme.AppCompat.Light` which, while it is designed to look and operate the same as the Material theme, is a support library designed to provide backward compatability for the Material theme all the way to Android 2.1 (API 7). My guess would be that the `PlacePicker` library only inherits the `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` attributes from the true Material theme and not the support library.

An easy way to test this would be to modify your `style.xml` file to use the real Material theme and see if this works:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#5665bb</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#41456b</item>
</style>
```

The only drawback of course is that the Material theme is only available in API ≥ 21, so, if this works, then you would be restricted to devices that utilize Lollipop only.

Lastly, as a sidenote, the `Theme.AppCompat` support libraries do not use the `android:` namespace, so your original `style.xml` file can be shortened as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#5665bb</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#41456b</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Setting the colours for the native material design didn't work for me. :(

Comment: Android. Where setting colors is rocket sciene

Answer (score 1):

> To fix issues toolbar theme android Place Picker on OS under Lollipop

```
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder(); 
Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(getActivity()); 
    // if Build version sdk is under Lollipop, add intent extra
    (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        intent.putExtra("primary_color", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        intent.putExtra("primary_color_dark", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }

//start intent
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER_CODE);
```